# UITableView self-sizing cells/sectionHeaders reload UI bug

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Lot of times I faced with the issue of cells/sectionHeaders "**flickering**" right when I **reloadData, reload some specific section/row**. Everything looks with correct frames if you just show the items. But when I need to reload them, then the bug appears.

And the bug is gone when I use hardcoded value for the height of cell, or height of section.

Here is the code

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 40
```

Section and row itself both have correct constraint. Then when I need to update the cell, I tried to call `reloadCell`, `reloadSection` and `reloadData`. Each method creates a flickering issue. Here is the gif - https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-bd4f8b762d.gif

**There are 2 issues**:

*Note:* I call `reloadData()` each time I click on cell. Almost sure that's not a big deal, cause it doesn't work fine with any of the way to update content.

**1**. When you are scrolled down and click some cell, it scroll you up for a little. And I also figured out that the position that it scrolls you to is dependent on the `estimated<Row/SectionHeader>Height` value. Can someone explain how exactly UITableView works with those values? When exactly it sets the the contentSize based on estimated values, and when and how it reloads itself to the final content size.

**2.** I added `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` to show you the bug with sectionHeader flickering that happens each time when I call `reloadData()`.

Are these known iOS bugs? Cause they really look so. I have correct constraints, I don't do anything custom. When I set hardcoded values and return them in usual `heightFor...` method, everything looks fine. But since self-sizing cells is native feature, I would like to use it finally at least once without any UI issues :)

**Update:**
Some additions to code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let (section, preference) = self.sectionPreferenceFor(indexPath: indexPath)

    if section.type == .Multiple {
        preference.selected = !preference.selected
    } else {
        (section.items!.array as! [Preference])!.forEach({ $0.selected = false })
        preference.selected = true
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

For showing bug #2 I just wrapped `tableView.reloadData()` by `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`

Here is what I have in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: String.init(describing: PreferenceMessageSectionHeaderView.self), bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: String.init(describing: PreferenceMessageSectionHeaderView.self))

self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: String.init(describing: PreferenceSectionHeaderView.self), bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: String.init(describing: PreferenceSectionHeaderView.self))
```

And, as usually nothing special in the configuration of rows/sections

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: String.init(describing: PreferenceMessageSectionHeaderView.self)) as?PreferenceMessageSectionHeaderView
        view?.configureWith(message: self.headerMessage)
        return view
    } else {
        let view = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: String.init(describing: PreferenceSectionHeaderView.self)) as? PreferenceSectionHeaderView
        view?.configureWith(title: section.name)
        return view
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let (section, preference) = self.sectionPreferenceFor(indexPath: indexPath)

    if section.type == .Single {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String.init(describing: RadioButtonCell.self)) as! RadioButtonCell
        cell.configureWith(title: preference.name, selected: preference.selected)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String.init(describing: CheckBoxCell.self)) as! CheckBoxCell
        cell.configureWith(title: preference.name, selected: preference.selected)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: @AaqibHussain sure. I updated the post.

Comment: did you try it by directly accessing your custom cell objects instead of reloading your tableView?

Comment: @AaqibHussain, I know it would fix the issue. And there are a lot of workarounds, but I'm trying to finally find a native solution. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with self-sizing cells, I don't know. That's why I decided to ask here...

Comment: @StasIvanov - I've seen similar things before, but never saw a resolution. I *think* it's either a "bug" or a "sorry, doesn't work well with multiple section headers".